# Why is it skipping the else part of my if-else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

It keeps skipping the else part of my statement. I just want it to print out of the invalid line if all the other restrictions are not met.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program_3
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
      String str = input.nextLine();
      boolean lowerCase = false;
      boolean upperCase = false;
      boolean number = false;
      char y;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
         y = str.charAt(i);
         if(Character.isUpperCase(y))
         {
            upperCase = true;
         }
         else if(Character.isDigit(y))
         {
            number = true;
         }
         else if(Character.isLowerCase(y))
         {
            lowerCase = true;
         }
      }
      if (lowerCase == true)
      {
         if (upperCase == true)
         {
            if (number == true)
            {
               if (str.length() >= 8)
               {
                  System.out.println("Verdict:\t Valid");
               }
            }
         }
      }
      else
         System.out.println("Verdict:\t Invalid");
   }
}
```

why does it skip and not print the invalid line when all ifs are not met?

Answer (score 5):

The `else` in your code relates only to the *outermost* `if`. 
So it will only be executed if `lowerCase == false`.

To fix this logic, combine all three conditions in a single `if`, i.e.:

```
  if (lowerCase == true && upperCase == true && number == true && str.length() >= 8)
  {
      System.out.println("Verdict:\t Valid");
  }
  else
     System.out.println("Verdict:\t Invalid");
```

---

Side note, booleans don't require explicit comparison to `true`, so you can write it shorter:

```
      if (lowerCase && upperCase && number && str.length() >= 8)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot! I do not know why i didnt think of that!

Answer (score 2):

The `else` condition is placed in the wrong place, it'll only be reached if the `lowerCase` condition is `false`. And anyway, we can simplify and combine all the `if`s in a single condition, what you meant to say was this:

```
if (lowerCase && upperCase && number && str.length() >= 8) {
   System.out.println("Verdict:\t Valid");
} else {
   System.out.println("Verdict:\t Invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code can b be simplified to show control-flow:

```
  if(lowerCase == true)
  {
      //lowerCase == true -> execute this code
      if( upperCase == true)...
  }else
      //lowerCase == false -> execute this code
      ...
```

The inner if-statements (which are exclusive btw.) don't execute the outer `else`-statements, if the condition is false. The logical correct version of your code would be:

```
if(lowerCase && upperCase && isNumber && str.length() > 8)
    System.out.println("Verdict:\t Valid");
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test password contains at least one lowercase character. As long as it does, the else statement will never execute. To test "if all conditions are true ... else ..." try the follwing:

```
if (lowerCase && upperCase && number && str.length >= 8) {
    // password ok
} else {
    // password not ok
}
```

By the way, as you can see I don't use lowerCase **== true** since it's not needed, lowerCase already is a boolean.